# SPServices - JQuery - Call to update list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, spservices

```
$().SPServices({
      operation: "UpdateListItems",
      async: false,
      batchCmd: "Update",
      listName: "TestList",
      ID: itemID,
      valuepairs: [["Status", 'requested']],
      completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
        alert("completed");
        itemRequested();
      }
  });
```

If I change batchCmd: to "New" this works giving me a new row in my list with the "Status" column as requested.  However what I want is to update the status column in a row that already exists with 'requested'.  The code here is not hitting the complete function but not adding requested to the list anywhere.

Comment: Maybe you should set a way to handling the `completeFunc` call in a more descriptive ways, like: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93256/proper-way-to-check-for-failed-spservices-call

Answer (score 0):

1. First, open the console (F12) and make sure you're not getting any errors.
2. Hard-code an ID to rule out a problem with your itemID variable, e.g. `ID: 1,`
3. Make sure "Status" is the [internal name of your column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/787/finding-the-internal-name-and-display-name-for-a-list-column).
4. Add a div to your page: `<div id='debug'></div>` and add the following code for debugging to your `completefunc` to get a detailed error message

   ```
   completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
      alert(Status);
      var out = $().SPServices.SPDebugXMLHttpResult({
      node: xData.responseXML
      });
      $("#debug").html("").append("<b>Debugging output:</b>" + out);
   }
   ```